# Generating exercises about extrema of $f(x,y)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials

I can generate many examples of functions $f(x,y)$ for which finding local extrema is a good exercise for students, for example $f(x,y)=x^3+y^3-3xy$,  $f(x, y) = x^3 + 3xy^2 − 51x − 24y$, $f (x, y) = xy + \ln y + x^2$. The general idea of solving them is to obtain a polynomial of a small degree, for which the roots are easy to obtain, because, e.g., some of them are integer or rational. However, I do not know how to obtain nontrivial, i.e., not of the type  $f(x,y)=(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2$, examples of functions with previously known extrema.

A long time ago I found a simple rule for memorizing the values of $\sin x$ for $x\in\{\pi/6,\pi/4,\pi/3,\pi/2\}$. I did not believe that it is not generally known. Indeed, many years later I found this observation in a written source.

In this case, I also believe that the mathematical society knows the general rules of generating many examples of easy but not trivial exercises, only I do not know them. Are such rules known to you?

Comment: This might be a better fit on [MESE](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I will confess that when I was writing my multivariable mathematics book I often generated "doable" exercises by using Mathematica ... putting in parameters, letting it give me the appropriate answers, and then choosing parameters to make things "nice." Of course, with linear algebra, it's very easy to go backwards and guarantee "nice" results; not so much with calculus.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you. I have just asked it there, but with a little hope. About 3300 questions versus over a million is a big difference.

Comment: The question on MESE can be found [here](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/25232/376).

Comment: @JW Well, I still remember what I added today. ;-)

Comment: Of course, but the link is for the convenience of others who may come across this question.